# Matlab - Connect image's pixels with a curve

Tags: matlab, image-processing, pixel, curve, spline

Good morning guys, I'll explain my problem.
I want to obtain a curve passing through the pixel-points' positions of a Canny edge of a free surface of water in a tank (problem of sloshing), so next I can work freely on the curve in an X-Y plane (for example, to compare 2 curves and add or subtract them).

I've tried with a function "Poly3" as here:

```
I = imread('20jh1g2.jpg');
I = im2bw(I);
imshow(I);

[r, c] = find(I);
r = -r + size(I,1);
figure;
plot(c,r,'.');
hold on;
f = polyfit(c, r, 3);
plot((min(c):max(c)),polyval(f,(min(c):max(c))), 'red', 'LineWidth', 3);
```

but the approximation can be too big if the surface is "more complex" (high vibrations).

Is there a function to connect each pixel to the next one? I've read something regarding "Spline function" but I didn't understand how to use it and if it is the solution.

This is an example of binary edge of my interest: [image]

How can I reproduct with Matlab "exactly" the same profile (without the bubbles), with NO approximation? I hope that I have clarified my concept.

Thanks you all for the help :)

Comment: Yous houl duse piecewise splines. First understand that if you want a polynomial (only one) to fit your curve trhough your points, you would need a polynomial of the order of your points-1. so if you have 200 points in the boundary, you'll need a 199 order polynomial, which obviously, its not a solution. Therefore you need some small polynomials that can stick one to another smoothly, and that's what splines are used for. They are piecewise smooth (depends on the order they are more or less). My mathematical nomenclature i snot completely rigth but I hope you understand the basics of why.

Comment: This is an example of binary edge of my interest:
http://i62.tinypic.com/23to3rq.png
How can I reproduct with Matlab "exactly" the same profile (without the bubbles), with NO approximation? I hope that I have clarified my concept.

Comment: You did. Did I clarify my concept?

Comment: If you need the exact profile you should just use your data.

Comment: @AnderBiguri sorry, but I didn't understand very well your concept :(

Comment: @0xMB  Mmh...how can I use my data?
PS: Sorry for the English, but it's not my language, so I have some difficulties

Comment: You have your 'coordinates' in `r` and `c` therefore you can compare, add and subtract.

Comment: Yes you've right, but my purpose is that it's possible this:
for example, I have 2 different water surfaces and I want represent the difference between them (third curve): can I plot the 3 of them (with the same  tendency of the real ones) on the same XY plane? So next I can set the coordinates in terms of lenghts :)

Comment: The idea is that if you want a polynomial to go through N poinnts, you need a polynomial of order N-1. Therefore if your curve has 200 points, you ned apolynomial of the form f(x)=x^199+a198*x^198+...+a2*x^2+a1*x+a0, so you will have 200 unknnowns to solve. Thats the only polynomial that will fit your conditions. Else, you can define a curve in pieces, most comonly done with cubic splines. Why cubic splines? because you need the curve to be continuus. You will need to define 199 splines thouhg.

Comment: @Ander Biguri Exactly, now I have understood your concept! But I think that this requires a good deal of time, isn't it? Above all, because I must handle different images...So I could use a minor number of cubic splines to make a more accurate approximation for more complex surfaces (for example: 200 points, I can use 10-20 splines to approximate better the waves in some points of the profile), have I right? :-)
Then, how can I set the spline code to connect "specific pixel points"?
ps: thanks for the help guys

Comment: @Firefly Yeah, the 200 order polynomial is NOT a viable option at all. The best option is splines. However, if you want for sure to include all your points, then you need 200 splines (its computationally really fast to compute, dont worry), however, probably 10-20 would create a good enough aproximation of the curve. Youll find lots of informations in google about how to represent a curve with splines

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! :)
I wanna ask you another question: I'm trying to compare the edges without interpolate and obtain the curve, but directly comparing the pixel positions on the same X-Y plane. I have 2 images 400x400 pixels, I plot the binary edges with the same x-y axes, next I compare directly (for example) the pixel y-coordinates for the same x-coordinate value and at last I obtain the x-y coordinate for the resulting point.
1) Is it possible create a macro to achieve this goal?
2) How can I change "only" the axes orientation without changing the image's position?